# Exoplayer 2: Playing mp4 from cacheDir

Tags: android, android-videoview, exoplayer, android-storage

I am downloading mp4 from server to cacheDir. Later I want to play this video using Exoplayer. But I am unable to do so.

I used following for playing server Url: (It worked fine)

```
extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoURL),
    cacheDataourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
```

Local url from cacheDir: (not working)

```
File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "/MP4/test.mp4");
extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(Uri.parse(file.toString(), 
    cacheDataourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), "/MP4/test.mp4");        
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);      
    DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(uri);
    final FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource();
    try {
        fileDataSource.open(dataSpec);
    } catch (FileDataSource.FileDataSourceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
        @Override
        public DataSource createDataSource() {
            return fileDataSource;
        }
    };
    CacheDataSourceFactory cacheDataSourceFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(cache, factory);
    MediaSource audioSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(fileDataSource.getUri(),
            cacheDataSourceFactory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(), null, null);
```

Comment: what is **cache** here?

Comment: @AjayMistry it might be a com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.SimpleCache object, for instance