# exoplayer2 is not playing local video from SD card (java.io.FileNotFoundException)

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to play a hardcoded video from SD card (not URL). I checked the file exists in the app folder into SD card but I am unable to play it. After searching in some threads at stackoverflow ([Playing mp4 from cacheDir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801596/exoplayer-2-playing-mp4-from-cachedir)), I could not play the video from the SD card. Here is my code:

```
public void initVideoPlayer(String path) {
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.wifi_video_popup);
    playerView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.player);
    fullscreenButton = playerView.findViewById(R.id.exo_fullscreen_icon);

    fullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          //...
        }
    });

    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    playerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FIXED_HEIGHT);

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, Util.getUserAgent(activity.getApplicationContext(), context.getString(R.string.app_name)));

    File file = new File(context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null), "file_1.mp4");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    DataSpec dataSpec = new DataSpec(uri);

    final FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource();
    try {
        fileDataSource.open(dataSpec);
    } catch (FileDataSource.FileDataSourceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DataSource.Factory factory = new DataSource.Factory() {
        @Override
        public DataSource createDataSource() {
            return fileDataSource;
        }
    };

    MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory)
            .createMediaSource(fileDataSource.getUri());

    player.prepare(videoSource);
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    dialog.show();
}
```

So, any indicator where things go wrong in my code?

========= Update =========

After carefully debugging the code, I noticed runtime error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/file_1.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

But the fact is that the file is there already. I also checked SD card in my macbook, and I noticed the file is located at:
`/Volumes/NO NAME/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/file_1.mp4` so why android is unable to find the file?

Finally, this is the access permission I have in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Comment: Apps do not have read/write access to arbitrary locations on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: but I do have access permission in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

Comment: Sorry, but those permissions do not give you access to arbitrary locations on removable storage.

Comment: but it is a location where I am saving the app videos to play them offline

Comment: My apologies! You are writing to an app-specific location on removable storage. However, your code for reading is pulling from external storage via `getExternalFilesDir(null)`. Your code for writing will be a bit different, using `getExternalFilesDirs(null)` (note the plural) and getting some item out of the returned array. Make sure that your code for coming up with the `File` is consistent, completely, between your read and write scenarios.

Comment: In another class, I write using `strAppDirectoryPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath();` `File file = new File(strAppDirectoryPath, filename);`

Answer (score 1):

If your device has Android 11 or more, you need to give the app permission to access and control all files in storage.

Of course you can navigate the user to allow this in storage permission using below code.

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                    if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                        val intent =
                            Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
                        val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                        intent.data = uri
                        startActivity(intent)

                    }
                }
```